# setup alerts to all users in public calander

Tags: calendar, public-folders, exchange-2003

I would like to setup a public calander which alerts all users that are part of this when apointments come up. i am using exchange 2003 not too sure if this is possible to setup or not.

Comment: [2003](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/share-your-calendar-in-outlook-2003-exchange-environment/) [2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc743438.aspx?ppud=4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook doesn't support Alerts/Reminders from Public calendars.

[From MS KB 186689](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186689/en-us) "XCLN: Reminders Do Not Start for Items in Public Folders":

> Because public folders are not specific to any one user or profile, there is no one for the reminder to remind. To receive reminders to specific appointments or meetings, use your mailbox calendar to make appointments and schedule meetings.

You can get the functionality by using an add-on such as the "[Extended reminder function for Microsoft® Outlook®, Public ShareFolder und Microsoft® Exchange Server](http://www.publicshareware.com/public-reminder-addin-description.php)":

> Public Reminder Add-In provides reminders from any email, calendar,
>   tasks or contacts folder in Microsoft Outlook, Public ShareFolder or
>   Microsoft Exchange Server.
>
> This allows you to set reminders on items in any folder in your
>   mailbox or PST file, secondary PST files, archive PST files or Public
>   Folders of Public ShareFolder or Microsoft Exchange Server.